# Incorrect results from c++ code

Tags: c++

Im writting a c++ code that is suppose to read in a person’s full name (first names and family name separated by spaces) from the keyboard, changes the first letter of the names into upper case if it is not in, and then displays the name on the screen.

The problem is everytime I try to compile my code I get on the screen the first names that i have inputed but not including the first first name of the list of the First names but on the other hand I do get the surname I have inputed. For example when I input "josh fred simon" as the first names and "Pirch" as Surname the program only outputs = "fred simon Pirch" without the name "josh".

Another thing is How to to change the first letter of the input names into upper case if it is not inputed in upper case ??

This is a copy of my code >>

```
#include<conio.h>  
#include<cctype>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

// main entry point for the program  
void main() {

  char FirstName[20];
  char SurName[20];

  cout << "Program to read the information about a person";  
  cout << "\nEnter your First Names please\n";  

  cin >> FirstName;  

  gets(FirstName);

  cout << "\nEnter your Surname please\n";      
  cin >> SurName;

  //Now displaying the information      
  cout<<"Details of Person\n\n";

  cout<<"Full Name of the Person: "<< FirstName << " " << SurName << endl;

  getch();  
}
```

Comment: Start by formatting your code, noone can possibly read it like this.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), #17. Oh, and #18. Oh, and #20. .. Possibly, also the rest.

Comment: @DanielSaska I think it is clear enough, if u can not read it then it is ur problem.

Comment: "ur problem"? Who's the one asking for help, here?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Im not here to argue with anyone so please if u know how to help me with my code u would do a big favor for me otherwise dont write something irrelevet to my question. thanks.

Comment: I was actually going to help, but after seeing your attitude, I decided against it. Maybe someone else will help you out.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading `FirstName` twice, first with `cin` and then again with `gets`.

```
cin >> FirstName;  
gets(FirstName); // remove this line
```

Also, use a single IO library in your code. Use `<iostream>` for C++ code and remove `<stdio.h>`

Comment: @user2088978 Use `std::getline` to read strings that are separated by spaces and `toUpper` to change a character to upper case.